# How to make monthly sums from daily values - function?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset of meteorological data every day for the period 1983 - 2019. I am doing some data wrangling and I would like to create a function which will take values for one variable and for a certain period and make a sum.

This will be used several times in the code, so I don't want to use .resample('MS').sum(). Moreover, I would like to be stronger in programming, so I am trying to solve it by 'written' function.

So dataset looks like this. I've just created a new variable 'MONTH'. But it could be a quarter or a half-year.

```
filled_values['MONTH'] = filled_values['DAY'].dt.strftime('%b %Y')
filled_values.tail(n=2)

out:
      DAY        RAIN   TEMP  TMAX   TMIN   WIND  MONTH
13030 2019-03-04 0.1240 22.38 26.500 18.840 1.16  Mar 2019
13031 2019-03-05 0.1900 22.77 29.220 17.510 1.08  Mar 2019
```

And now I am trying to create the function.

```
prec_sums_per_month = []
def sums_prec(dataset, date, variable_for_sum, new_variable, new_dataset): 
    for date in dataset.items:
        new_dataset[new_variable] = variable_for_sum.sum()
    return new_dataset

prec_sums_per_month = sums_prec(filled_values, 'MONTH', 'RAIN', 'RAIN_MONTH', prec_sums_per_month)
print(prec_sums_per_month)
```

I've expected the new DataFrame (or dictionary?) with 'MONTH' variable and sum of rain for that month. But here is my result:

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: you could use pandas groupby function, `df.groupby(['MONTH']).aggregate('RAIN').sum()`

Comment: Thank you, but this approach turns back sums ordered by specific months for every year.

Comment: What do you want exactly, sums per month irrespective of year?

Comment: Ideally, sums of variables for every month chronologically order by year. E.g. Rain sums for March 2019, for February 2019, for January 2019. I am looking to solve it by python function.